# Not getting the array from Node.js to AJAX

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, node.js

Hi it seems based on my code that I am not reaching or responding the array from Node.js to AJAX no other errors or what not but I can not seem to figure out what is wrong with my code see below. Thank you in advance for your help!

> AJAX code below:

```
function update() {
let rq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    rq.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(rq.readyState == 4) {
        var arr = JSON.parse(rq.responseText);
        for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        document.getElementById("message").innerHTML += "<p>" + arr[i] + "</p>";
        }
    }
    rq.open("GET", "/messages", true);
    rq.send();
  }
}
```

> Node.js code to handle GET:

```
if(req.method == "GET") {
  req.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log("You are reching GET-DATA");
  });
  req.on('end', function() {
    console.log("You are reching GET-END");
    res.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type" : "application/json" })
    console.log(JSON.stringify(arr))
    var toString = JSON.stringify(arr);
    res.end(JSON.stringify(arr));
  });
}
```

[image]

I am reaching *console.log(req.readystate)* and it ouputs *"1"*, *alert("Your program reached rq.onreadystatechange");* and *alert("Your program reached rq.onreadystatechange = 4");* and then after awhile the response will now be received and I see error on the console.

[image]

Comment: Put console.log and check what response you are getting.

Comment: Proper code indentation would make it a lot easier to see what's wrong and the network tab in the Chrome debugger would be a big help to see where to look for the problem.

Comment: @jfriend00: I have no error in console or in the browser, I also cannot console.log() the array when it is send back to AJAX. It does not reach the readystate 4.

Comment: @maheshiv: No print is output if I do a console.log(rq.responseText) it is not reaching the readystate = 4.

Comment: My point is that if you looked at the network tab in the debugger, you would see that your request was never being sent which would have been a vital clue.

Comment: @jfriend00: Ohh okay thank you for the information, I am not sure on how to read it I will edit my post and add it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ajax code has the `open` and `send` within the `onreadystatechange` callback. You need to move that out of there:

```
function update() {
    console.log('update called');
    let rq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    rq.onreadystatechange = function() {
        console.log('readyState: ' + rq.readyState);
        if(rq.readyState == 4) {
            console.log('responseText: ' + rq.responseText);
            var arr = JSON.parse(rq.responseText);
            for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                document.getElementById("message").innerHTML += "<p>" + arr[i] + "</p>";
            }
        }
    };
    // moved out of above function
    rq.open("GET", "/messages", true);
    rq.send();
}
```

By adding some `console.log` calls you can also better follow what is (not) happening.

Comment: I added it out outside the function thank you for pointing that out.